# assigning value to a 2-Dimensional array

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

How can I assign value to a 2-dimensional array?
My array is

String[][] arr=new String[2][3];

And when I am assigning value to this array, application is stopped.

Example: arr[0][0]="hello";

Please give me the solution...

Comment: Is it possible the assignment occurs before the array is initialized?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your application stops due to some other reason. Simply doing

```
String[][] arr = new String[2][3];
arr[0][0] = "hello";
```

should be perfectly fine.

See

- [Two-dimensional arrays as arrays of arrays](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D-2.html)
- [Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Java: Multi-Dimensional Arrays](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page89.html)
- [Multi-dimensional Arrays](http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/14833-multidimensional-arrays.html)